# Send Contact Form To Different Email, Depending on Select Value?

Tags: magento2, contact-form

Does anyone have any experience customizing the Magento Contact module to send the values to different emails depending on email? I'm trying to figure out how to add a select field that would determine the email destination.

Comment: Did you mean based on customer email id entered, email should be sent to different- different emails ?

Comment: The email would go to the value of the select field. So essentially selecting a department to determine the email's recipient.